# Retrieving group membership in LDAP

Tags: ldap

I am using a sample LDAP which is available online [here](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/).

I want to retrieve a user's group membership given their uid. In the example, Gauss (`uid=gauss`) is a member of the Mathematicians group (`ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com`).

I tried several LDAP queries but I cannot seem to find the one that returns me the `ou=mathematicians` given the `uid`.

There are a lot of similar answers on SO but none seem to fit this very simple use case.

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve the group membership by simply using the `uid` as the groupmemberships are stored using the `uniqueMember`-attribute which requires a complete DN as value. Therefore you'll have to use a searchfilter like `uniqueMember=uid=gauss,dc=example,dc=com`.

You might think "that's great, so I just add `uid=gauss` to the baseDN and I'm finished". You might not always have luck with that as it's not defined that users have to be located right in the baseDN. They might be distributed acros the complete LDAP-tree and then it's going to be tough. But when you already have searched for the user (IE for binding) you got the DN back "for free" so you can use that on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried and it worked just fine... Search Base: dc=example,dc=com  -  Filter: (uniqueMember=uid=euler,dc=example,dc=com)

Comment: Oddly enough I cannot use * in the uniqueMember search string i.e. uniqueMember=*euler* doesn't work

Comment: Sadly you can use the ```*```only *behind* an expression. So ```uniqueMember=euler*``` should work whereas ```uniqueMember=*uler``` won't. I'm not sure whether that's by design or not, it's just *hard-learned* personal experience ;)

Comment: Thanks for that. So I will have to build the entire dn like you said in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get right what you want to do, but retrieving group membership is done by a filter similar to this one:

`(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<<<USER-DN>>>))`

I always pull the user dn with a seperate search:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=<<<USER LOGON NAME>>>))
```

I don't know if uid, dn  and samaccountname can be used in every filter interchangeable, but try it with uid=<<>> instead.

See this article for details : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx